# pick a nested hash which has a given key value pair in puppet

Tags: puppet

I have this data structure in hieradata

```
server:
  host: 'foo.bar.baz'
  public_host:
    common:
      host: 'foo.bar.baz'
    internal:
      host: 'some.internal.name'
      partition:
        name: 'int'
        service_port:
          8443:
    nonvs:
      partition:
        name: 'BLA'
        manage_virtualserver: false
```

Now I need a way to pick the full nested hash in $server['public_host'] which has a given key value pair.

E.g. I'm looking for ...['partition']['name'] = 'BLA' and will get $server['public_host']['nonvs']

Hopefully it's clear what I want to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can solve this problem using `filter`:

```rb
  $server = lookup('server')    
  $public_host = $server['public_host']

  $filtered_data = $public_host.filter |$k, $v| {
    has_key($v, 'partition') and has_key($v['partition'], 'name')
      and $v['partition']['name'] == 'BLA'
  }
```

You'll need stdlib to get the `has_key()` function too.

If you wanted the resulting Hash to include Hashes nested at the level of the `partition` key, as indicated in the comments, you might be tempted to then use `reduce` on the data:

```rb
  $reduced_data = $filtered_data.reduce({}) |$memo, $x| {
    $memo + $x[1]
  }
```

`$x` is the [key, value] pair for each of the top level keys in $filtered_data, so `$x[1]` returns the Hashes inside the top level Hashes.

For example, if $filtered_data is `{a => {d => 1}, b => {e => 2}, c => {f => 3}}`, $reduced_data would be `{d => 1, e => 2, f => 3}`.

This won't help you, however, because you would end up with multiple `partition` keys in the top level of your resulting Hash. Since it's not possible for a Hash to contain duplicate keys, all but one of the partitions would be silently discarded.

These are based on some examples in the docs [here](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/5.4/function.html#filter) and [here](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/5.4/function.html#reduce).

Comment: looks good but $filtered_data should only contain the values of the nested hashes.

Comment: i place an if around your has_key ... madness and inside the curly brakets $v to get the reduced result. But this won't work

Comment: Nested at where?

Comment: finally i need a hash with all keys and nested hashes for that public_host hash which matches the condition. 
In the example the final hash should look like this `{partition => {name => 'BLA', manage_virtualserver => false}}`
But filter seems not to be the right methode for this because it returns the full hash if the conditions evaluate to true.

Comment: I'm not sure if there's a better way to do it, but you can get what you want by then adding a line: `$nested = $filtered_data[keys($filtered_data)[0]]`.

Comment: Not that this is any better, but I think you can remove the `stdlib` dependency if you `defined($v['partition'])`. Removing `stdlib` as a dependency is probably not as valuable as readability though.

Comment: I just simplified it a little by using $v instead of $public_host[$k].

Comment: @ChristianMeißner, I updated the answer to address your requirement that the Hash be nested at the partition level.